# Checking for free slots in a booking system

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looking for assistance as I'm trying to create a testing booking system but each person needs to be booked onto a specific machine (laptop) at a specific time. Please see below database:

[image: Database]

Apologies for the poor image but hopefully you get the idea. I've got the database to show me booked records, but I want to be able to see whats left.

I currently have 10 machines each with three time slots which is easier you visualise like this:

```
****************************************************************
* Machine/Laptop *   Time Slot   *      Name      *     Test   *
****************************************************************
*                * 09:30 - 11:00 * John Adams     * English    *
*    Laptop 1    * 11:00 - 13:00 * Book Slot      * Free       *
*                * 13:00 - 14:00 * Raj Patel      * English    *
****************************************************************
*                * 09:00 - 12:00 * Joe King       * English    *
*    Laptop 2    * 11:00 - 13:00 * Andrew Lil     * Maths      *
*                * 13:00 - 12:00 * Book Slot      * Free       *
****************************************************************
```

Now I don't know how to make a single database query work, but for example purposes heres a really dirty way to do it which would involve checking the database 30 times each time the page is loaded:

```
$sql = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` 
                          FROM event_booking 
                          INNER JOIN event_machine
                          ON event_booking.machine_id=event_machine.id
                          INNER JOIN event_machine_time
                          ON event_booking.machine_time_id=event_machine_time.id
                          WHERE information_id = '.$_GET["id"].' AND event_machine.id=1 AND event_machine_time.id=2');
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchObject();
    if ($result->total > 0) { echo 'Slot Booked'; } else { echo '<a href="booking.php">Book Slot</a>'; }
```

For each time this is called I would have to change the `event_machine.id=? AND event_machine_time.id=?` to call the specific slot.

I'm sure I'm approaching this wrong so any help would be great :)

EDIT:

If it helps heres what I'm going for
[image]

As you can see the purple buttons are the active slots and the darker one are booked. For a demo I could only fit 5 of the 10 laptops but you get the idea.

Here is the database query I'm using to call all of the event bookings. This shows all of the bookings made within the event from `event_information` then I use `fetchAll` into a table. But I don't know if something could be used with this query to get the booking ID's over to the time slots?

```
$Event_list = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT
                                  event_booking.id,
                                  event_booking.live,
                                  event_booking.confirmation_email,
                                  event_candidate.firstname,
                                  event_candidate.surname,
                                  event_candidate.email,
                                  event_information.type,
                                  event_machine.id AS machine_get_id,
                                  event_machine.name,
                                  event_machine_time.id AS machine_time_get_id,
                                  event_machine_time.start_time AS machine_start_time,
                                  event_machine_time.end_time AS machine_end_time
                                  FROM event_booking
                                  INNER JOIN event_candidate
                                  ON event_booking.candidate_id=event_candidate.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_information
                                  ON event_booking.information_id=event_information.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_machine
                                  ON event_booking.machine_id=event_machine.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_machine_time
                                  ON event_booking.machine_time_id=event_machine_time.id
                                  WHERE information_id = ?'); 
    $Event_list->execute(array($_GET["id"]));
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Another option would be to scrap the `event_machine` and add a column called `machine_name` into `event_machine_time` then use the following:

```
$Event_Times = $dbconn->query('SELECT *
                                   FROM event_machine_time
                                   LEFT JOIN event_booking
                                   ON event_machine_time.id=event_booking.machine_time_id
                                   ');
```

Use this within a table:

```
<td>
        <?php foreach ($Event_Times->fetchAll() as $Event_Times_Row) { ?>
            <?php if($Event_Times_Row["machine_name"] == "Laptop 1") { ?>
            <a class="button<?php if($Event_Times_Row["information_id"] == $_GET["id"]) { echo " button-disabled"; } ?>" href="#"><?php echo date("G:i", strtotime($Event_Times_Row["start_time"])); ?></a>
        <?php } } ?>
</td>
```

However I would need to call this 10 times and I don't think `fetchAll` allows this and I would need to repeat this db query 10 times to make it work.

Comment: Not your current issue but you are misusing prepared statements. Variables should be bound. `WHERE information_id = ?` then `$sql->execute(array($_GET["id"]));`

Comment: Apologies I whipped this up as an example, but you are spot on I do for all live projects

Comment: What's the advantage of storing event_machine_time separately?

Comment: Nothing really, it was just my approach, otherwise machine and time could be in the same table, just it would mean I would have three rows each with with same machine name. I suppose its useful for expanding times and machines, but I can change it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167887/sql-query-for-hotel-room-reservation/43289025#43289025 this is what you're after, it isn't ?

Comment: could you show us what you expect to have ? and provide some data from your db, so we can make test

Comment: I've added some extra bits, but I can join `event_machine` and `event_machine_time` if works better

Answer (score 1):

Your approach need some corrections:

1. `event_machine_time` table must be related to `event_machine` table. So `event_machine_time` table must have a field name `event_machine_id`.
2. After that you need not a direct relation between `event_booking` and `event_machine` tables, because it is discoverable from relation other relation in the previous step.
3. It is better to drop `start_date`& `end_date` fields from `event_information` table, because they are equal. you must insert a new filed `event_date` representing both of them.
4. You must drop `start_time` and `end_time` fields from `event_information` table, because they are discoverable from `event_machine_time` table in relation with the main table to maintain data integration.
5. It is better to include `event_information` table in the main `booking_event` table, because there is a 1-to-1 relation between these tables.

After you make these changes all you want to do will be very simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help but this is the conclusion I came to:

I amended my database by dropping the `event_machine` table as shown here:
[image: Database 2]

In the `event_booking` table I added a column called `machine_name` and made three entries with the same laptop name, but different timings e.g.

```
****************************************
* machine_name * start_time * end_time *
****************************************
* Laptop 1     * 09:30      * 11:00    *
* Laptop 1     * 11:30      * 13:00    *
* Laptop 1     * 13:30      * 15:00    *
* Laptop 2     * 09:30      * 11:00    *
* Laptop 2     * 11:30      * 13:00    *
* Laptop 2     * 13:30      * 15:00    *
****************************************
```

Using this I then used the following database relationships, which I ran as a `fetchAll()` loop:

```
$Event_Times = $dbconn->query('SELECT *
                                   FROM event_machine_time
                                   LEFT JOIN event_booking
                                   ON event_machine_time.id=event_booking.machine_time_id
                                   ORDER BY start_time
                                   ');
$Event_Times_Loop = $Event_Times->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I ran the loop 10 times (7 shown in the photo) within a HTML table:

```
<td>
    <?php foreach ($Event_Times_Loop as $Event_Times_Row) { ?>
    <?php if($Event_Times_Row["machine_name"] == "Laptop 1") { ?>
    <a class="button<?php if($Event_Times_Row["information_id"] == $_GET["id"]) { echo " button-disabled"; } ?>" href="#"><?php echo date("G:i", strtotime($Event_Times_Row["start_time"])); ?></a>
    <?php } } ?>
</td>
```

[image: Screenshot]

So with a bit of CSS to disable the buttons where someone has already booked it seems to work pretty nicely. There's most likely a much better, cleaner solution but al least I have something that works. Also apologies for my terminology I'm sure I've got that wrong too :)

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Your solution about `machine_name` has normalizing problem.

Comment: Ok, It works. but it has normalizing problem. that means that you cannot get a report for machines (without times) for example.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand, it's because of my understanding of the problem

Comment: Read 1st & 2nd steps of my answer.

Comment: But step 1 doesn't apply anymore as I've merged `event_machine_time` and `event_machine` together

Comment: When you merge these two tables you lose the data of machines (laptops) separately, because machine name and  specifications, are identical for 1 machine and must be repeat in merged table. so for data integrity reasons you must have separate `event_machine` table for storing machine specs and reporting vs. machines.